# Able to call generic SwiftUI View when in my project but issues once it's in a package and imported

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui, swift-package

I have a SwiftUI app that calls a View with passed in Views, methods, and variables. This view, let's call it `DisplayView` is general enough that I'm able to call it in different ways and have it display really different things. This worked great but I recently moved `Display View` to it's own package and I'm now having trouble calling it.

To create a simple example I started a new app and created a single general view to show how I call it. This WORKS.

```swift
// Shared Display View
public struct DisplayView<Content: View>: View {
    // The view we need to display
    let content: Content
    // The methods that need to be executed
    var aMethod: () -> Void
    
    // Boolean
    @Binding var aBoundVariable:Bool
    
    // Regular Variable
    var aName:String
    
    public var body: some View {
            content
#if os(macOS)
                .padding()
#endif
    }
}
```

Result of this:

[image: Code shown along with app result when I call the general DisplayView located within my project.]

When I instead move the `DisplayView` to it's own package and import it I'm having issues calling it.

First the newly formed `DisplayView` now looks like:

```swift
import SwiftUI

// Shared Display View for all the Core Data display views
public struct DisplayView<Content: View>: View {
    // The view we need to display
    let content: Content
    // The methods that need to be executed
    var aMethod: () -> Void
    
    // Boolean
    @Binding var aBoundVariable:Bool
    
    // Regular Variable
    var aName:String
    
    public init(content: any View, aMethod: @escaping () -> Void, aBoundVariable: Binding<Bool>, aName: String) {
        self.content = content as! Content
        self.aMethod = aMethod
        _aBoundVariable = aBoundVariable
        self.aName = aName
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
            content
#if os(macOS)
                .padding()
#endif
    }
}
```

I then committed,tagged, etc my package and imported it into the first app shown. I commented out the old `DisplayView` code, imported my package, and attempted to call the new `DisplayView`.

Code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import thePackage

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var aVariable: Bool = false
    let aName = "hey"
    
    var body: some View {
        DisplayView(content: displayText(), aMethod: randomMethod, aBoundVariable: $aVariable, aName: aName)
    }

    private func randomMethod() {
        print("random method")
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func displayText() -> some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
}

//// Shared Display View --> Now using imported package
//public struct DisplayView<Content: View>: View {
// ...
//}
```

Just calling the method like before gets this error: `Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred` or image:
[image: Error: Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred]

When I hit fix I see a placeholder

```swift
DisplayView<<#Content: View#>>(content: displayText(), aMethod: randomMethod, aBoundVariable: $aVariable, aName: aName)
```

but can't figure out how to use it properly. I've tried several iterations of all sorts including:

View
[image: using View]
some View
[image: some View]
and @ViewBuilder based on other questions I saw online.
[image: and @ViewBuilder based on other questions I saw online]

I'd love to switch `DisplayView` into a package so I can use it in several projects but can't figure out how to call it properly when it's a package.

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Comment: Why is your init with `any View` instead of simply `Content`? In the working View that's not the case.

Comment: @hallo Because when I used `View` in the init (the working one didn't have a visible init) I had an error of `Use of protocol 'View' as a type must be written 'any View'` with a fix to switch it to `any View`.

Comment: Pretty sure your `init` is wrong then. It shouldn't take `View` nor `any View` but `Content` like the automatically generated `init` in your working example would.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. If you make your comment the answer I can mark it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `init` to take `Content` instead of `any View` then it should work.

```swift
import SwiftUI

// Shared Display View for all the Core Data display views
public struct DisplayView<Content: View>: View {
    // The view we need to display
    let content: Content
    // The methods that need to be executed
    var aMethod: () -> Void
    
    // Boolean
    @Binding var aBoundVariable:Bool
    
    // Regular Variable
    var aName:String
    
    public init(content: Content, aMethod: @escaping () -> Void, aBoundVariable: Binding<Bool>, aName: String) {
        self.content = content
        self.aMethod = aMethod
        _aBoundVariable = aBoundVariable
        self.aName = aName
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
            content
#if os(macOS)
                .padding()
#endif
    }
}
```